# Jaxb:global binding Double Type Conversion Using XMLAdapter

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have an element defined as an xsd:double. If I try and place a value say 285 into the element and then I marshal it I get an output of 285.0... That is fine .However, if I put a value in of say  285292746, I get an output of  2.85292746E8 when I marshal.
I like something so that double output does not get converted into scientific notation with decimal? Basically I want 285292746 or 2852292746.0000000

java.lang.Double.toString() uses "computerized scientific notation" for certain values which produce isues for xml.

I  know double representation of given value is fine. But  the fact the value was in exponential format,  The system that I am working on is accept my XML but does not know what to do with the exponential value and that causes my program not to work correctly.  Changing xsd:double type in WSDL or server is not feasible for me. I am working on client side.

I came across Jaxb:binding for xsd:double type. I am still having hard time to fix the issue to send values double value in non –exponents format.

```
package com.logger.client 
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class JaxbDoubleSerializer  extends XmlAdapter<String, Double>
{


    public Double unmarshal(String value) {
        return ((double)javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDouble(value));
    }

    public String marshal(Double value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDouble((double)(double)value));
    }

}
```

I need help how to use DoubleSerializer so that I can pass values without exponents. I tried using xmlAdapter Annotation in my class MyLogClient.java. I need to know how I can solve this situation.

```
package com.logger.client 
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;


public class MyLogClient 
{
   //Private member fields

  /** Object factory used to create user-and-role specific objects. */
    private static final ObjectFactory _of = new ObjectFactory();

     @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JaxbDoubleSerializer.class)
   public JAXBElement<Double> msgFileId;

       @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JaxbDoubleSerializer.class)
   public Double dNumber;


public final void createEntry;
    (
        final String userName,
        final String time,
        final String logMsgStringId,
        final Params logMsgParamsVal,
        final Integer logMessageFieldID
    )

    throws JAXBException
    {

       JAXBElement<String> username = _of.createParamsParam(userName);
      JAXBElement<String> strTime       = _of.createLogRequestTime(time);


        // Build the LogRequest request.
       final LogRequest _LogRequest = _of.createLogRequest();
       _LogRequest.setUserName(userName);
       _LogRequest.setTime(strTime);

        //Following is the main problem
        int nMsgArgs =  285292746;
       dNumber = Double.parseDouble(Integer.toString(nMsgArgs));  
      //After parsing double Value I get dNumber is now  2.85292746E8

      //MsgFile Id is of Type JAXBElement<Double>
      //CreateLogMessageIdentifier takes Double param
      //So the main problem is here..the value of double field in soap request 
      //is being sent in exponential format. I need to send as I explained above
      //285292746.

       msgFileId   = _of.createLogMessageIdentifier(dNumber); 

      JAXBElement<String> strIdVal = _of.createLogMessageFileId(logMsgStringId);

      final LogMessage logMessage = _of.createLogMessage();

     JAXBElement<Params> _logMsgParams =_of.createLogMessageParams(logMsgParamsVal);

     //Following is where I am trying to use marshall for double type.

     JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("package com.logger.client ");
     context.createMarshaller().marshal(msgFileId, System.out);

      logMessage.setIdentifier(msgFileId);  //Method takes JAXBElement<Double>

      logMessage.setFileId(strIdVal );
      logMessage.setParams(_logMsgParams);

      JAXBElement<LogMessage> logMsgValue = _of.createLogRequestLogMessage(logMessage);


        _LogRequest.setLogMessage(logMsgValue);

        // Set the log entry
        port.log(_LogRequest); //Request is sent to server.
```

}

WSDL xsd:type declaration is below:-

```
  <xsd:complexType name="LogMessage">
         <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="fileId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
        <xsd:element name="identifier" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
        <xsd:element name="params" type="tns:Params" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
         </xsd:sequence>
           </xsd:complexType>
```

Output for identifier field is:-

```
     <identifier> 2.85292746E8</indentifier> 

Whereas I want to send as. Because system does accept/recognize following types.

<identifier> 285292746</indentifier> 
or 
<identifier> 285292746.00000000</indentifier>
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use an external bindings file like the following:

**binding.xml**

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jxb:globalBindings>
            <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.Double"
                xmlType="xs:double"
                parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDouble"
                printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDouble" />
    </jxb:globalBindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

**root.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:double" />
            <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:double" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**XJC Call**

```
xjc -d out -b binding.xml root.xsd
```

**Root**

The class generated for the root type will have `XmlAdapter` classes registered on the Double properties:

```
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import org.w3._2001.xmlschema.Adapter1;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "root", propOrder = {
    "foo",
    "bar"
})
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "double")
    protected Double foo;
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "double")
    protected Double bar;

    public Double getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Double value) {
        this.foo = value;
    }

    public Double getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Double value) {
        this.bar = value;
    }

}
```

**Adapter1**

The `XmlAdapter` utilizes the methods you configured in the binding.xml file.

```
package org.w3._2001.xmlschema;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class Adapter1 extends XmlAdapter<String, Double> {

    public Double unmarshal(String value) {
        return (javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDouble(value));
    }

    public String marshal(Double value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDouble(value));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank-you so much. I am going to try this way. I don't have xsd file but source code is generated from wsdl file that file is published through URL. I assume I would have to use wsimport or something to do binding with wsdl . xjc -d out -b binding.xml (http://localhost/MyClient.wsdl) or wsimport -d out -b binding.xml location.wsdl.

Answer (score 1):

The best way might be to use a custom binding (javaType clause) with your JAXB compiler. Documentation can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html). Depending if you have to marshal and unmarshall doubles, the solution might be as simple as overriding the mapping to something such as a BigDecimal at the global level (with the understanding that although doubles and decimals are totally different things, you seem to want a decimal representation), or to use a datatype converter (the link above gives you examples for all these options).

Comment: Would you give some specific examples? Would you think that xml adapter option is fine. I tried to use as shown above in my example JAxDouble Serialzer but not sure what i am missing.